# Как установить библиотеку curl на mac? - c++

Tags: c++, xcode, curl, mac

Возможно ли вообще использовать эту библиотеку на mac и как это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Все не сложно, если вы знакомы с командной строкой: http://macappstore.org/curl/